# Multiple Contributions in a Single Contribution page?

Tags: webform-civicrm, contributions

I want to set it up so that a user can purchase 2 or more of a contribution from the same page.  Each contribution needs to be separated - I can't just combine 2 payments into one field of a price set.

What we are trying to set up is a way for members to pay 'back-dues'. Each back-due payment has a custom field 'month back dues are for'. The idea is that if they are 2 months behind on dues, they can pay for two separate 'back-dues' financial types. We were going to use webforms to set the custom date field up so that it would default one of the payments to -1 Month, and the other as -2 Months.

In some ways we're trying to get a 'store' type functionality, but using civicrm so we can use the smart-groups, ACL's, etc.  I wonder if it would be possible to make it so that products purchased through drupal commerce could be assigned civicrm financial types?

Another way to think of it might be if we could 1. use civi price sets on drupal webforms, and 2. enable civi custom fields for the price set - especially if the quantity in the price set is more than 1 - enable the custom field for each 1 of the quantity.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Alternatively, if we can use multiple contribution pages in a single drupal webform, that would be great.

Comment: Hi Matt - can you expand a bit more on what you mean by 'purchase more than one contribution' and clarify why line items (price sets) fail to deliver your requirement. Basically the answer to this is 'no', so hoping we can help find you something that works and meets your needs.

Comment: So we're trying to set up a way for members to pay 'back-dues'.  Each back-due payment has a custom field 'month back dues are for'.  The idea is that if they are 2 months behind on dues, they can pay for two separate 'back-dues' financial types.  We were going to use webforms to set the custom date field up so that it would default one of the payments to -1 Month, and the other as -2 Months.

Comment: cool. pasted above in the OP as may get some more useful answers.

Comment: Can you create a price set with 12 line items (Jan, Feb, March). Then they just enter an amount for the month they are paying.

Comment: @carlmiller, not really, cause we would need this for months in different years, - example someone wants to catch up on Sept 2017's dues which they missed, they pay that, and stay current on their dues for many years.  Years down the line we take a look and are not sure which month / year that payment of back dues was for - is it recent?  old?

Comment: I do not know how to make it automatic, but you could create a price set with 3-4 months (Current and the past 2-3), then each month you add the new month and delete a past one.